# Bootstrap slider decimal trailing issue

Tags: java, jquery-ui-slider, trailing, bootstrap-slider

[image]

> Look into the first image, last trailing zero truncates in a slider.
>   From back-end side data are coming as per the rounding, but not
>   showing properly in the slider.

[image]

JSP Page :

[image]

> Did not find any solution, Please help me on this.

---

TIA

Comment: Pass the label array as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider").slider({
            ticks : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],   
            ticks_labels: ['0.66', '0.69', '0.72', '0.74', '0.77','0.80', '0.83', '0.85']
 });
```

I guess this will work for you..define ticks and it's relative tick labels